# Read in a file, splitting and then writing out desired output

Tags: python

I am very new to python, and am having some problems I can't seem to find answers to. 
I have a large file I am trying to read in and then split and write out specific information. I am having trouble with the read in and split, where it is only printing the same thing over and over again.

```
blast_output = open("blast.txt").read()
for line in blast_output:
    subFields = [item.split('|') for item in blast_output.split()]
    print(str(subFields[0][0]) + "\t" + str(subFields[0][1]) + "\t" + str(subFields[1][3]) + "\t" + str(subFields[2][0]))
```

My input file has many rows that look like this:

```
c0_g1_i1|m.1    gi|74665200|sp|Q9HGP0.1|PVG4_SCHPO      100.00  372     0       0       1       372     1       372     0.0       754
c1002_g1_i1|m.801       gi|1723464|sp|Q10302.1|YD49_SCHPO       100.00  646     0       0       1       646     1       646     0.0      1310
c1003_g1_i1|m.803       gi|74631197|sp|Q6BDR8.1|NSE4_SCHPO      100.00  246     0       0       1       246     1       246     1e-179    502
c1004_g1_i1|m.804       gi|74676184|sp|O94325.1|PEX5_SCHPO      100.00  598     0       0       1       598     1       598     0.0      1227
```

The output I am receiving is this:

```
c0_g1_i1    m.1 Q9HGP0.1    100.00
c0_g1_i1    m.1 Q9HGP0.1    100.00
c0_g1_i1    m.1 Q9HGP0.1    100.00
c0_g1_i1    m.1 Q9HGP0.1    100.00
```

But what I am wanting is

```
c0_g1_i1      m.1    Q9HGP0.1    100.0
c1002_g1_i1   m.801  Q10302.1    100.0
c1003_g1_i1   m.803  Q6BDR8.1    100.0
c1004_g1_i1   m.804  O94325.1    100.0
```

Comment: You should use line.split() in the third line.

Comment: `blast_output` is a string, and iterating over a string gives you characters, not lines. Remove the `.read()` at the beginning to iterate over the lines of the file.

Comment: Try *unwinding*/expanding your list comprehension and assign all those fields to variables.  Then you can inspect the individual variables (maybe with print statements) to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the `read` method of the file object, just iterate over it, line by line.  Then replace `blast_output` with `line` in the for loop to avoid repeating the same action across all the iterations:

```
with open("blast.txt") as blast_output:
    for line in blast_output:
        subFields = [item.split('|') for item in line.split()]
        print("{:15}{:10}{:10}{:10}".format(subFields[0][0], subFields[0][1], 
                                            subFields[0][1], subFields[1][3], subFields[2][0]))
```

I have *opened* the file in a context using `with`, so closing is automatically done by Python. I have also used *string formatting* to build the final string.

---

```
c0_g1_i1       m.1       m.1       Q9HGP0.1  
c1002_g1_i1    m.801     m.801     Q10302.1  
c1003_g1_i1    m.803     m.803     Q6BDR8.1  
c1004_g1_i1    m.804     m.804     O94325.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Great question.  You are taking the same input over and over again with this line

```
subFields = [item.split('|') for item in blast_output.split()]
```

The python 2.x version looks like this:

```
blast_output = open("blast.txt").read()
for line in blast_output:
    subFields = [item.split('|') for item in line.split()]
    print(str(subFields[0][0]) + "\t" + str(subFields[0][1]) + "\t" + str(subFields[1][3]) + "\t" + str(subFields[2][0]))
```

see Moses Koledoye's version for the Python 3.x formatted niceness

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies why it isn't working. I guess the text I am using is showing the version 2, but I need the version 3 :)